# How to make sure keras model outputs same accuracy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I set the following:

```
np.random.seed(7)
# split data to train, validate, test (60%, 20%, 20%)
train, validate, test = np.split(data, [int(.6*len(data)), int(.8*len(data))])
history = model.fit(train, train, epochs=1, batch_size=32, verbose=1, shuffle=True,
                    validation_data=(validate, validate), callbacks=[cb])
score = model.evaluate(test, test, verbose=1)
```

`shuffle=True` shouldn't matter here since I'm only training for one epoch.
Now from what I've read this should ensure that my model's accuracy is always the same after training from scratch, but the accuracy results for various runs are 48%, 48%, 56%, 48%, 56%, 47.5% and so on. So I'm wondering if there is something else I have to do to ensure that the resulting accuracy stays the same?

Answer (score 0):

The parameters of the model are initialized differently everytime you fit the model, even if it is for the same data. So it will result in different accuracies. If you are insistent on getting the same accuracy, run the model once, save the parameters in a file and then load them again when you are running the code. Refer [Keras Documentation](https://keras.io/) for more details.

Comment: The reason I want the exact same results every time is so that I can try different parameters and compare them with one another. To make the comparison fair, I need to set default baseline so that every "setting" can compete on even ground. Is this generally not possible?

Comment: I don't think you can get the exact same results by playing around with the parameters. You change the parameters, predictions will change and so will the accuracy. I don't understand what exactly do you mean by 'setting'.